# onPause() and onResume() not called in Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am developing an Android app with Xamarin Android in Visual Studio.
I have a MainActivity which will be nothing more than 2 buttons to login or register. Once one of those buttons is tapped a new activity is started like this:

```
sign_in_button.Click += delegate 
{
    var login_activity = new Intent(this, typeof(Login));
    StartActivity(login_activity);
};
```

In that activity I do everything I need to log in with the API, everything works fine, on success I save the token and call Finish(); to go back to MainActivity.

```
if(response_text != "\"wrong\"")
{
    General.SaveToken(this, response_text);
    Finish();
}
```

Now, the problem is that I need to tell somehow to MainActivity that the user logged in successfully. To do that I was thinking to check if there is a token saved in the SharedPreferences, if so then start the activity needed. In this way it should also work when the app is opened, if a token is already saved, go to x activity
My problem is that all of the activity events (onPause, onRestart, onResume, etc) are never called... In the MainActivity I added a test just to verify that it gets called like this:

```
protected override void OnPause()
{
    base.OnPause();
    Console.WriteLine("TEEEEEEEEST");
    //set alert for executing the task
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alert.SetTitle("Activity event");
    alert.SetMessage("The activity is paused");
    alert.SetPositiveButton("Ok", (senderAlert, args) =>
    {

    });

    Dialog dialog = alert.Create();
    dialog.Show();
}
```

But the dialog never appears, neither TEEEEEEEEST is shown in the console. I also tried to add breakpoints but they are not hit.
Of course, I tried all the other events, all with the same result: nothing.
As far as I understood from the activity lifecycle documentation, onPause is called automatically when StartActivity is called, and onResume after the "child" activity calls Finish(); or when the back button is pressed.
What am I missing/doing wrong??
I read that it can be a problem of Visual Studio, so I tried both on the provided android simulator and on a real device (LGE Nexus 5 running Android 6.0.1) with the same result.
Please help!
Thanks, everyone in advance!

Comment: are you using appcompat library

Comment: Isn't that for Xamarin Forms (the multi platform one)? I'm using Xamarin Android

Comment: No appcompat library is a backward compatibility library for Android

Comment: Please add log on every lifecycle's method, OnCreate, OnResume,OnPause,OnRestart..., and then run your app to check it. And use [Diagnostic MSBuild output](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/troubleshooting/) to get more information about debug to check what is wrong with your app.

Comment: I did that and OnActivityResult() magically started to work, even after turning it back off... I think this is a problem of my environment, not of my code. Would that be possible? Anyway with those options I had 25000 lines of output, where do I even begin to check it?

Comment: Yes, these options will show many infos, you can check it from the `OnCreate()` method's log. You can use VS installer's repair to repair your VS, or try reinstall, after all, it is not a complex problem.

Comment: @JoeLv-MSFT thanks man, reinstalled VS and everything works like a charm. I hate Microsoft so bad...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the problem was Visual Studio, I reinstalled it and all of the Activity events get called properly.
Thanks everyone for the support

Answer (score 3):

First make sure that you are not creating any instance of your activity manually, that could be a reason why an instance of an activity doesn't receive life cycle callbacks.

But if your main activity shows up / you click a button on it, then they're being called, but something maybe is wrong with your environment/IDE.

A good solution for your original problem is to use `startActivityForResult()`.

So your login activity can be started for result, and returns `RESULT_OK` if login is successful or `RESULT_CANCELLED` if not

And in your MainActivity you check the result by overriding `onActivityResult`

EDIT:

Okay, let's debug your attempts

- I have no idea what showing a Dialog in onPause will do, because basically you are showing a dialog when your activity is losing focus.
- Read [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/debugging/android-debug-log/) that `Console` doesn't really work on Android, please use Android's Log class instead.

Comment: From what I read the activity looses focus only when everything inside onPause() is done. Anyway, it might be a silly idea to show a dialog inside onPause, I did that only because I have tried everything else. I used StartActivityForResult and OnActivityResult, but no results.

Comment: Is OnActivityResult called? can you check with Android logs?

Comment: Not, it's not called. I added Log.Info("MainActivity", "this is an info message") but nothing shows up in the log. I also tried to put breakpoints and they are not getting hit. By the way, thanks a lot for the help

Comment: Put the log somewhere has to be called, the onCreate() of you main activity, if the log doesn't get printed, your logcat setup is the problem if not, then you might be looking at the wrong place. You are very welcome

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and it was solved by deleting the `bin` and `obj` folders, then I rebuilt the project and it worked. I was using Visual Studio Community 2019

Answer (score 0):

none of them worked for me .

my system: xamarin.android @ VS 2015  +update_v3

**what fixed for me:**

```
// this doesnt alone workeddddd!!!!!!! the following things + maybe this settings
[Activity( /**..name and icon things **/
   AlwaysRetainTaskState =true,
   LaunchMode = Android.Content.PM.LaunchMode.SingleTask )]
public class act_main : Activity 
{
}
```

tried to update vs2015  then canceled after 30 seconds
triead install appcompat from nuget whic failed..

i opened  android sdk manger.
    deleted  api 23 sdk
    installed  api 26 sdk   (not the images only sdk which is 60-70mb)
    installed

project properties > android manifest

```
minimum android ver : and 4.1  - api 16 - jelly bean
target  android ver :  
            from    : android 6 - api 23 - marsmallow
             to     : android 8 - api 26 - oreo
```

and somehow this all fixed.